# Is this the only planar cubic graph with six squares and two hexagons?

Tags: graph-theory

Is this the only planar cubic graph with six squares (five inside, one outside) and two hexagons?

[image]

How to prove that?

Allowing for multiple edges I can find another, but without not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed the unique such graph.  To see this let $G$ be a cubic planar graph with six square faces and two hexagonal faces.  We have
$3|V(G)|=2|E(G)|=6(4)+2(6)=36$.  Thus, $V(G)=12$ and $E(G)=18$.  By stereographic projection, we may assume that the outerface of $G$ is a hexagon $H:=x_1x_2\dots x_6$.  Let $y_i$ be the neighbour of $x_i$ which is in the interior of $H$.  Since, $G$ has no faces of length $3$, all $y_1, \dots, y_6$ are distinct. The subgraph $G[Y]$ induced by $y_1, \dots, y_6$ is $2$-regular, and is hence a $6$-cycle or two $3$-cycles.  The latter is impossible since $G$ has no faces of length $3$.  Thus, $G[Y]$ is a $6$-cycle.  Suppose that $y_iy_j \in E(G[Y])$. Then the path $x_iy_iy_jx_j$ separates $H$.  Thus, $y_i$ and $y_j$ must be consecutive, or we violate planarity.  Thus, $G[Y]$ is a hexagon $H':=y_1\dots y_6$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a planar version of a hexagonal prism - a neater version with straight edges can be drawn by putting one hexagon inside the other and joining equivalent vertices.

You have 8 Faces, 12 Vertices and 18 Edges to play with. (two hexagons and six squares equals 18 edges, use F+V-E=2 to find the number of vertices)

If the hexagons do not share an edge they take up all the vertices and you have six edges to add, which is the design you found.

If they share one edge, then you have two vertices and seven edges to add.

It is also possible to draw two hexagons in the plane which share two edges and give four vertices and eight edges to add.

I can find solutions in both of these cases if we are allowed to have vertices of order $2$ in the configuration. If vertices must have order at least $3$, then all vertices must have order exactly $3$ (otherwise vertices of order 2 are balanced by others of order 4). I'm out of time now, but I can't see solutions with all vertices of order three except in the first case.

---

Just to complete the argument for vertices of order 3.

With two hexagons joined along an edge, number the vertices $1-10$ clockwise from one of the ends of the edge where they meet. We can add nothing to point $1$ so edges $1-2$ and $10-1$ are sides of the same square in the final configuration. If we complete the square by joining $10-3$ we "trap" point 2 - it needs to join to something, but there isn't anything to join to. Likewise joining $2-9$ traps 10. So our only choice is to add point $11$ and lines $2-11$ and $10-11$ to complete the square. We can repeat a similar argument with $11-2$ and $2-3$ except that vertex $10$ already has order $3$ so we can't use $10-3$. So we need another vertex to add, and then we've run out before we've even considered the position at $5-6$ and $6-7$.

The configuration with hexagons joined at two edges can be drawn by placing a small square inside a large one and joining pairs of diagonally opposite corners to get two hexagons beteen the squares. Then the inner square has two diagonal vertices of order $3$ and two of order $2$. The only thing we can do with the opposite vertices is to join them by a diagonal with a vertex in the middle. Now the middle vertex has order $2$ and there is nothing we can do about that-it is a trapped vertex as all its neighbours already have degree $3$, so that configuration doesn't work.

ON THE OTHER HAND if we allow vertices of order $2$, whenever we have a square, we can put a diagonal in with a central vertex and divide one square into two. This can be done in various ways with the outside and inside of this second configuration.

With the first configuration, join, for example $1-4$, $4-7$, $7-10$ to create an outside square, and then add two suitably placed diagonals. There are many other possibilities.

Note finally that if we were to join the hexagons at three edges, all the vertices would already have degree $3$ (joining consecutive edges traps vertices of degree 2) and we could add nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For a planar cubic graph $G$, we have $E=\frac{3}{2}V$, where $E$ and $V$ denote the number of edges and vertices of $G$, respectively. The number of faces is $F=8$ by assumption. If $G$ is connected then we have $V-E+F=2$, and hence $V=12$ and $E=18$.

Consider one of the hexagonal faces; it is bounded by six edges connecting six vertices. As $G$ is cubic, each of these vertices has precisely one 'outgoing' edge, i.e. an edge that does not bound this hexagon. As there are no triangular faces, no two of these outgoing edges are adjacent, yielding the following configuration:

[image]

A bit of trial and error shows that there is only one way to make this graph into a planar cubic graph without triangles:

[image]

See Tony Huynh's answer for a rigorous proof of the latter claim.

This is the graph you already found, and this is the only such graph.